# How to assign values to a row based on the order of list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this question has been asked in another way, but I want to be sure word this one is worded exactly as I understand it.  I'm still learning pandas, so bear with me.

I have 3 dataframes that share a common key.  I need to assign the values in the columns of dataframe A into the Values of Dataframe B based on the key values of the dataframe C.  To better illustrate here are my examples.

```
options= [["Option1", "Description1"], ["Option2", "Description2"], ["Option3", "Description3"]]
dfA = pd.DataFrame(options, columns = ["Option", "Description"]) 

links= [["Link1", "LinkDescription1"], ["Link2", "LinkDescription2"], ["Link3", "LinkDescription3"]]
dfB = pd.DataFrame(links, columns = ["Link", "LinkDescription"]) 

master_ledger = [["Option1", "Link1"], ["Option2", "Link2"], ["Option3", "Link3"]]

dfC = pd.DataFrame(master_ledger, columns = ["Option", "Link"])
```

Looking at each of these DF's we see:

```
dfA
Out[14]: 
    Option   Description
0  Option1  Description1
1  Option2  Description2
2  Option3  Description3
dfB
Out[15]: 
    Link   LinkDescription
0  Link1  LinkDescription1
1  Link2  LinkDescription2
2  Link3  LinkDescription3
dfC
Out[16]: 
    Option   Link
0  Option1  Link1
1  Option2  Link2
2  Option3  Link3
```

What I'm trying do is assign LinkDescription's in DFB the values from the option descriptions in dfA, but based on the option / link relationship inside dfC.  So psuedo terms, this could be written as:

dfB["LinkDiscripiton"] = dfA["Description"] 
->where dfB["LINK_ID"] == dfC["LINK_ID"] and dfA["OPT_ID"] == dfC["OPT_ID"]

The expected change would be applied to dfB and it would look like:

```
dfB
Out[15]: 
    Link   LinkDescription
0  Link1  Description1
1  Link2  Description2
2  Link3  Description3
```

I'm not really sure how to approach this, so I don't have examples of my previous approaches.  Thanks for the help.

Update#

Thanks to Yatu's Merge suggestion, I found the following to do the trick and assign the option descriptions into dfB's link Descriptions:

```
df_temp = dfA.merge(dfC, on='Option')
df_temp.merge(dfB, on = 'Link')[['Link','Description']]
dfB[["Link", "LinkDescription"]] = df_temp[["Link", "Description"]]    

dfB:
Out[63]: 
    Link LinkDescription
0  Link1          Description1
1  Link3          Description2
2  Link2          Description3
```

Also just to better explain the desired output.  If I had defined dfA to be:
    options= [["Option1", "Bronze"], ["Option2", "Gold"], ["Option3", "Silver"]]
    dfA = pd.DataFrame(options, columns = ["Option", "Description"])

```
dfA
Out[68]: 
    Option Description
0  Option1      Bronze
1  Option2        Gold
2  Option3      Silver
```

Then dfB would be changed to:

```
Out[63]: 
    Link LinkDescription
0  Link1          Bronze
1  Link3            Gold
2  Link2          Silver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in order to merge the three dataframes on their corresponding keys, and then keep the columns that belong to `dfB`:

```
df_temp = dfA.merge(dfC, on='Option').merge(dfB, on = 'Link')[['Link','Description']]

   Link   Description
0  Link1  Description1
1  Link2  Description2
2  Link3  Description3
```

Comment: Ok this is what I needed.  However there was a slight change in my case.  I needed the Link descriptions updated to be that of the option descriptions.  So instead of [['Link', 'LinkDescription']],  just put 'Description' instead of 'LinkDescripiton'.  And the desired output occurs.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, updated the answer @RockAndRoleCoder. You're welcome